# npx create-react-app is not installing with yarn

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am using `npx create-react-app <app-name>` to create react app. I have installed yarn on my machine. Using this command react app is installing with npm. But previously it was installed with yarn.

```
npm version: 8.3.0
node version: 17.3.0
yarn version: 1.22.17
os: windows 10 pro
git version: 2.34.1.windows.1
```

***Previously installing was like this:***

[image]

***Now installing like this:***

[image]

I want yarn package manager instead of node package manager. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#yarn

Answer (score 1):

try :
`yarn create react-app appname`